# php/ajax form send mail AND save data to db

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a contact form that's works now and i need to store data to db before sending the mail.

FORM: Just an email and message to simplify this code :

```
<fieldset id="contact_form">
 <div id="result"></div>
 <label for="email"><span>Email : *</span>
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  />
 </label>
 <label for="message"><span>Message : *</span>
   <textarea name="message" id="message" ></textarea>
 </label>
 <label>
   <button class="submit_btn" id="submit_btn">Envoyer</button>
 </label>
</fieldset>
```

PROCEED: send data with ajax to contact.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
var user_message    = $('textarea[name=message]').val();
if(proceed)
{
var post_data = new FormData();
post_data.append( 'userEmail', user_email );
post_data.append( 'userMessage',user_message);
$.ajax({
   url: 'contactus.php',
   data: post_data,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   type: 'POST',
   dataType:'json',
   success: function(data){
   if(data.type == 'error')
     {
     output = '<div class="error">'+data.text+'</div>';
     }else{
     output = '<div class="success">'+data.text+'</div>';
     }
    }
  });
 }
 });
});
```

CONTACT.php : get form data and send mail and show message (error or success)

```
include ("connexion.php");
if($_POST)
{
// SAVE DATA
$sql = 'INSERT INTO historique_contact VALUES ("", "tibo", "message")';
mysql_query ($sql) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
// SEND DATA
$to     = "mail@gmail.com"; 
$from   = $_POST["userEmail"]; 
$subject        = 'Contact'; 
$user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mail_body       .="Email:".$user_Email;
$mail_body       .="Message:".$user_Message; 
$headers =  'From: '.$from_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"';
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);
if(!$sentMail) //output success or failure messages
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Error...'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Success'));
    die($output);
}
}
```

Comment: So basically your question is... "How do I save data to a database in PHP?"  Start with any tutorial on PHP and MySQL.  There are *countless* examples and tutorials online to walk you through this introductory functionality.  We'll gladly help if you get stuck somewhere, but Stack Overflow doesn't seek to replace existing tutorials.

Comment: No, i know how to save data to db in php. But it didn't work if i put the code in the if condition (connexion to db added in other included file).     `$sql = 'INSERT INTO historique_contact VALUES ("", "tibo", "message")';
    mysql_query ($sql) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());`

Comment: The fact that the code in the question shows no attempt to use the database at all seems to suggest otherwise.  If you have code with which you need help, *show that code*.  If it's producing an error or failing in some way, *tell us the error*.  As stated before, in its current form your question is simply asking for a PHP/MySQL tutorial.  We don't provide those.

Comment: Question updated. If i clic submit, nothing happens and it keeps loading

Comment: If the page truly keeps loading then presumably there's some problem in your `connexion.php` file.  Once you can get it to actually execute the query, `mysql_error()` will tell you the next problem.  (Assuming your host still supports the old `mysql_*` extension.  It's been deprecated for many years.)  Your SQL query has invalid syntax because you're using double-quotes instead of single-quotes.  Additionally we have no way of knowing if that `INSERT` attempt is even meaningful for your table structure, and that empty value is pretty suspect.

Comment: I had to add all fields in select. It's working now. Thanks.